# Can a development Apple TV be upgraded to the current tvOS?

Tags: appletv

I got a development Apple TV from last fall (the second version) and was curious if it can be upgraded to current tvOS (9.2?). I plugged it in and didn't see the App Store on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. Connect the device to your computer using the USB cable and use iTunes to update the OS. Alternatively, you can install the configuration profile available in the Member Center of [developer.apple.com](https://developer.apple.com/).

Comment: cool - would something like this work? http://www.amazon.com/Cable-Matters-USB-C-USB-A-Black/dp/B00S8GU2OC I don't have the original packaging (not sure if that included a usb cable). thx

Comment: @timpone Yes, this should work. Only the first round of development kits included a USB cable — the second round omitted it. I used the iTunes method myself but I subsequently used the configuration profile which doesn't require a cable.